# Data frame as a resulting output and summarize them in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a main data frame with 5 columns (variables) and 1000 rows.

The desired output for each row entry is another data frame (with 10 columns and 100 rows each) generated/computed based on the variables from each row of the main data frame.

Also, the final result should be the sum of all resulting data frames.

I'm requesting for R codes.

Example:

**Main data frame:**

```
     |  Var 1   |   Var2   |    Var3   |   Var4   |   Var5   |   Desired Output   
     | -------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | -------- | ------------------ 
  1  |   10     |     25   |     3     |   100    |    10%   |        df1         
  2  |    3     |     32   |     1     |   350    |     5%   |        df2         
  3  |    0     |     45   |     3     |   120    |     2%   |        df3                 
   .
   .
   .
1000 |    5     |     38   |    18     |   430    |     2%   |      df1000
```

**Desired Output:**

sum all cells of **df1, df2, df3 until df1000**

where

**df1:**

```
    |    Output1   | Output2 = C2  |  ...  |          Output10                 
    | ------------ | ------------- |       | --------------------------------    
 1  |  (10 * 3)+1  |    10% ^ 1    |       | prod(C2r1:C2r1)= .10            
 2  |  (10 * 3)+2  |    10% ^ 2    |       | prod(C2r1:C2r2)= .11         
 3  |  (10 * 3)+3  |    10% ^ 3    |       | prod(C2r1:C2r3)= .111              
    ...
100 | (10 * 3)+100 |   10% ^ 100   |       | prod(C2r1:C2r100)=0.111111111
```

**df2:**

```
    |    Output1   | Output2 = C2  |  ...  |          Output10                    
    | ------------ | ------------- |       | --------------------------------  
 1  |  (3 * 1) +1  |     5% ^ 1    |       | prod(C2r1:C2r1)= .05            
 2  |  (3 * 1) +2  |     5% ^ 2    |       | prod(C2r1:C2r2)= .0525       
 3  |  (3 * 1) +3  |     5% ^ 3    |       | prod(C2r1:C2r3)= 0.052625          
   ...
100 |  (3 * 1)+100 |    5% ^ 100   |       | prod(C2r1:C2r100)= 0.0526316
```

.
.
.

**df1000:**

```
    |    Output1   | Output2 = C2  |  ...  |          Output10                    
    | ------------ | ------------- |       | --------------------------------   
 1  | (5 * 18) +1  |     2% ^ 1    |       | prod(C2r1:C2r1)= 0.02           
 2  | (5 * 18) +2  |     2% ^ 2    |       | prod(C2r1:C2r2)= 0.0204      
 3  | (5 * 18) +3  |     2% ^ 3    |       | prod(C2r1:C2r3)= 0.020408         
  ...
100 | (5 * 18)+100 |    2% ^ 100   |       | prod(C2r1:C2r100)= 0.02040816
```

Final Results should be:

**final_df**

```
    |              Output1 = C1           |...|          Output10 = C10                    
    |-------------------------------------|---|---------------------------------   
 1  | df1C1r1 + df2C1r1 +...+ df1000C1r1  |   |df1C10r1 +df2C10r1+...+df1000C10r1
 2  | df1C1r2 + df2C1r2 +...+ df1000C1r2  |   |df1C10r2 +df2C10r2+...+df1000C10r2
 3  | df1C1r3 + df2C1r3 +...+ df1000C1r3  |   |df1C10r3 +df2C10r3+...+df1000C10r3
  ...
100 |df1C1r100+df2C1r100+...+ df1000C1r100|   |df1C10r100+df2C10r100+...+df1000C10r100
```

I tried the loop per row of the main data frame but I only get results from the last variables used.

Here's the sample codes:

```
main_df <- read_excel (main_df)

for ( i in 1 : nrow (main_df)) { 

   Var1  <-  as.numeric(main_df$Var1[i])
   Var2  <-  as.numeric(main_df$Var2[i])
   Var3  <-  as.numeric(main_df$Var3[i])
   Var4  <-  as.numeric(format(as.numeric(main_df$Var4[i]), nsmall=4))
   Var5  <-  as.numeric(main_df$Var5[i])


df <- tibble ( t        = 1 : 100,
               Output1  = ( Var1 * Var3 ) + t,
               Output2  = ( Var5 ) ^ t 
               Output10 = cumprod ( Output2 ))                  
 }


 final_df <-  # sum of all dfs
```

A way other than looping will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

---

Say these are the 5 rows to be computed as the main data frame:

[screenshot of the first 5 rows sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzJpN.png)

I should be getting these results for a period of 1 to 10 only.

[generated results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F214g.png)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [ask] and edit your question to meet community guidelines.   You'll need to tell us what technologies you are working with and show your code, as well as tell us what you expected and what you obseerved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer a question that doesn't include sample data that we can run directly, but I think something like this could work.

There are a few parts of this I don't understand, like isn't Output10 the *sum* of those calculated ranges (e.g. 10% + 10%^2 = 0.11) and not their product (10% x 10%^2 = 0.0001)? Which do you want?

```
library(tidyverse)
main_df |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  complete(period = 1:100) |>
  mutate(Output1  = (Var1 * Var3) + period,
         Output2  = Var5 ^ period,
         Output10 = cumsum(Output2), .by = id) |>
  # at this point if you want separate df's, you could use
  # group_by(id) |> group_split()
  summarize(across(Output1:Output10, sum), .by = period)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, Jon. This is almost what I want except it only summarizes per period of its corresponding resulting data frame. How can I get the summary of all data frames generated in 1 final data frame. Thanks again. ◡̈

Comment: have edited my question with sample photos. thank you.

Comment: final_df is expected to be 100 rows long, one for each period, no? That's what my last line was meant to produce. If you want to examine separate data frames, skip that step and instead split the data by `id`, using eg base `split` or `dplyr::group_split`.

Comment: Yes, the final df should be 100 rows long just like the individual resulting output (computed based on the variables from each row of the main df). But please note that the resulting dfs are independent of to the main df (not attached to it). So the rows from the main df wont affect the resulting dfs because they should generate 100 rows as is. Thanks!